# How to use Elasticsearch plugin-defined filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have created a plugin for Elasticsearch and have installed it successfully (http://localhost:9200/_nodes/plugins/ shows it installed.)  But I can't seem to use it in my queries - I only get errors.  "ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]".  It seems like I need a different lang setting.  But I've tried 'lang': 'java'.  No joy.  I've tried lang: expression.  Then I get "ExpressionScriptCompilationException[Unknown variable [maxmind] in expression".  How do I access the plugin I've created?  Or do I need to do something more to register it?

I've been following this excellent guide:
https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-native-script-example

But it says nothing about how queries should be written.

My AbstractPlugin:

```
package org.elasticsearch.plugin.maxmind;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.elasticsearch.common.collect.Lists;
import org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Module;
import org.elasticsearch.plugins.AbstractPlugin;
import org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptModule;

import org.elasticsearch.plugin.maxmind.GeoLoc;

public class MaxMind extends AbstractPlugin {
    @Override public String name() {
        return "maxmind";
    }

    @Override public String description() {
        return "Plugin to annotate ip addresses with maxmind geo data";
    }

    // Thanks https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-native-script-example
    public void onModule(ScriptModule module) {
        module.registerScript("geoloc", GeoLoc.Factory.class);
    }
}
```

Note the name "geoloc".  Is that the name I use in my query?

My GeoLoc module:

```
package org.elasticsearch.plugin.maxmind;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptException;
import org.elasticsearch.common.Nullable;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.XContentMapValues;
import org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues;
import org.elasticsearch.script.AbstractSearchScript;
import org.elasticsearch.script.ExecutableScript;
import org.elasticsearch.script.NativeScriptFactory;

public class GeoLoc extends AbstractSearchScript {

    public static class Factory implements NativeScriptFactory {

        // called on every search on every shard
        @Override
        public ExecutableScript newScript
            (@Nullable Map<String, Object> params)
        {
            String fieldName = params == null ? null:
                XContentMapValues.nodeStringValue(params.get("field"), null);
            if (fieldName == null) {
                throw new ScriptException("Missing field parameter");
            }
            return new GeoLoc(fieldName);
        }
    }

    private final String fieldName;

    private GeoLoc(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        ScriptDocValues docValue = (ScriptDocValues) doc().get(fieldName);
        if (docValue != null && !docValue.isEmpty()) {
            // TODO: real geolocation here
            HashMap fakeloc = new HashMap<String, String>();
            fakeloc.put("lat", "1.123");
            fakeloc.put("lon", "44.001");
            fakeloc.put("basedon", docValue);
            return fakeloc;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

My query:

```
{
    "_source": [
        "uri",
        "user_agent",
        "server_ip",
        "server_port",
        "client_ip",
        "client_port"
    ],
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {}
        }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "test1": {
            "params": {
                "field": "client_ip"
            },
            "script": "geoloc"  // is this right?
        }
    },
    "size": 1
}
```

Comment: I know you tried `lang: java`, but does it work with `lang: native`?

Comment: Woohoo!  Thanks @LeeH.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to specify `lang: "native"` with your script, any script written in Java and registered with `registerScript` is the "native" type.